# Функция вычисления времени. Javascript

Tags: javascript, функции

Уважаемые форумчане, прошу помощи. Необходимо написать Функцию для подсчета необходимого времени для преодоления переданного расстояния со средней скоростью (передаются через prompt). Учтите, что через каждые 4 часа дороги водителю необходимо делать перерыв на 1 час - именно эта часть - проблема
Буду бесконечно признательна, если потратите время на объяснение решения. Заранее спасибо всем за помощь.

```
function countTime() {
  let dist = +prompt('Введите расстояние (число)');
  let avSpeed = +prompt('Введите среднюю скорость, с которой планируете двигаться (число)');
  let time = dist / avSpeed;
  let relax = 0;

  if (dist <= 300 && avSpeed <= 100 // или, как вариант, time <= 4) {
    document.write(`На преодоление расстояния ${dist} километров со скоростью ${avSpeed} км/ч вам потребуется ${time} ч. Отдых не требуется`);
  }else{
    if (time % 5 = 0){
      relax++
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Приведите,пожалуйста, пример своей реализации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте разбирать.

```js
let distance = prompt("Введите расстояние");
let speed = prompt("Введите среднюю скорость");

let timeInWay = distance/speed;

let timeInRest = (timeInWay%4 == 0)? (timeInWay/4 | 0) - 1: timeInWay/4| 0;

let timeTotal = distance/speed + timeInRest;

alert(`Общее время в пути Время в пути = ${timeTotal} часов`);
```

Как я понял проблема в вычислении времени на отдыхе, так ка время в пути не составляет проблем.

я так понимаю

> **каждые 4 часа дороги водителю необходимо делать перерыв на 1 час** - *это касается только если по истечении 4 часов нужно продолжать движение иначе этот час не добавляется.*

```
Пример 1.

Расстояние - 15 км
Скорость - 4 км/ч
Время в пути - 3.75


Пример 2.

Расстояние - 16 км
Скорость - 4 км/ч
Время в пути - 4


Пример 3.

Расстояние - 17 км
Скорость - 4 км/ч
Время в пути - 5.25 - поскольку после часового привала 
                      водитель должен ещё проехать один километр 
                      4 часа + 1 час отдых + 0.25 час итого 5.25
```

всё вычисляется по формуле

```
let timeInRest = (timeInWay%4) ==  0? (timeInWay/4 | 0) - 1: timeInWay/4| 0;
```

Если время в пути кратно 4, топоследний привал делать нет необходимости, т.е это `(timeInWay/4 | 0) - 1`.

Comment: timeInWay/4 | 0 это округление не беспокойтесь тут

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее? let timeInRest = (timeInWay/4) == (timeInWay/4 | 0)? (timeInWay/4 | 0) - 1: timeInWay/4| 0; У нас только 5 занятие по js. Правильно ли я понимаю: если время делится  на 4 без остатка - это вот это (timeInWay/4) == (timeInWay/4 | 0), то в случае true возвращает timeInWay/4 | 0) - 1, а если нет timeInWay/4| 0. кстати, timeInWay%4 == 0 это imeInWay/4 | 0 или нет. Простите, тупая(((

Comment: Да правильно подмечено, подправил формулу

Comment: А можно я вас побеспокою еще немного. Можете подробнее объяснить вот эту конструкцию? (timeInWay/4 | 0) - 1: timeInWay/4| 0;

Comment: @Alisa Это вторая часть оператора ?

Comment: Я поняла. Меня интересует такая запись округления (4 | 0). Я только математические объекты встречала. Что за знак | . Я спрашиваю, чтоб запомнить и дальше использовать.

Comment: @Alisa, это [побитовое ИЛИ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/conflicting/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators_7c8eb9475d97a4a734c5991857698560#_.28bitwise_or.29)

Comment: А или не так ли пишется? - ||

Comment: @Alisa || это логическое или, | побитовое или.

Comment: Спасибо большое. сейчас открою статью про это - почитаю подробнее.

Comment: @Alisa если ответ помог то можете пометить как полезный.